# How to store macrons in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I would like to add maori macrons like ā in phpmyadmin but it keeps getting replaced by a ?. What settings do I need to change to make this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

On the phpMyAdmin wiki, an article explains why data gets garbled and how to prevent it:
http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Garbled_data